# Conditional with Ip Address

Tags: global-variables

This one has me baffled.

I'd like to show some content based on the Global variable IP Address. But none of these work:

```
{if {ip_address} != 127.0.0.2}SHOW THIS{/if}
```

OR

```
{if {ip_address} != '127.0.0.2'}SHOW THIS{/if}
```

OR

```
{if '{ip_address}' != '127.0.0.2'}SHOW THIS{/if}
```

I would expect at least the last conditional to work. Is this a parsing issue?

Comment: Thank Low and Bhahkar. Low; I should have referred to your Parse List PDF, I've got it tucked away somewhere. I thought it might be something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `{ip_address}` is one of the standard global variables that is [parsed last](http://loweblog.com/downloads/ee-parse-order.pdf), even after advanced conditionals. That means you can't use it in a conditional.

You can use [Mo’ Variables](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mo-variables) (or [Low Variables](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-variables) if you’re already using it) to have `{logged_in_ip_address}` available as an early parsed var, so you *can* use it in conditionals.

Answer (score 2):

As EE parses `{ip_address}` after advanced conditionals it easy enough to get that data parsed sooner. I haven't got Low Variables installed on this site otherwise I would use it.

Instead you could add it as a variable to config.php:

```
$config['ipaddress'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Or I've actually added to my bootstrap file but it achieves the same thing.

Comment: Elliot Lewis - This worked perfectly: $config['ipaddress'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; Added to Config.php file and all is well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This standard global variable should work with logged in member. See here http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/single_variables.html#ip-address